# how isModified function is work in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to understand `isModified` function in mongoose . I am beginner to it and I am following a video tutorial but did not able to understand it fully .Could someone please help me to understand how it work ? how `!this.isModified` function is work in below code example

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
});
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: `if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }`   I am trying to understand this point .

Comment: Sorry, I meant what about that code is hard to understand? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: In other words you need to be a lot more explicit about what you do and don't understand. Give us a starting point based on your understanding.  Take a  few minutes to thoroughly read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are creating new user, in a prehook you have the mentioned if statement:

```
// The exclamation mark before this will change returned false to true, and true to false 
if (!this.isModified("password")) {  
     next();
}
```

So, lets say you are creating a new user, and you are using this ^ code in pre hook:

- The **new user password will be treated by "isModified" method as modified** (because it is new), **so it will return true**. Another example, when you are updating password of exisitng user, property "pasword" of user object  will be treated as modified, becouse you modified this password, so it is not hashed, and it has to be.
- BUT! The **exclamation mark** in if conditionals turns **true** to **false**.
- In the case of the password of anew user, we have false in the if statement, so we are not calling "next()", (this next() would end our entire hook) and code below is executed, our new password is going to be hashed.
- In the case of an old user, with an already hashed password, there is no need to hash it again, so this code execution will not hash an already hashed password. This case can happen when you are changing some user data, without changing the password, and of course pre save hook is called and is checking if it needs to hash the password or not.